# Sending "any key" to a subprocess called from a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

On a Windows machine I use Python 3.6 to run a Wildfly command like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("C:\wildfly\bin\jboss-cli.bat")
```

When the subprocess finishes it prints `"Please press any key to continue..."` and waits for the user input.

Is it possible to redirect the pressing of any key to this process?

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of run

Answer (score 0):

The issue here isn't with python, it is with windows. When a windows cli application terminates, it always prompts the user with the `"Please press any key to continue..."` that you are seeing. Using the REPL or interactive python can get you around this but the root issue is how the CLI for windows works, not python.

Thanks!

Comment: Strange, when I run command line applications on my windows machine, I don't see a "press any key to continue" prompt. Do you have any documentation describing when this message appears?

Comment: I'm guessing that python runs the pause command to stop the terminal from closing as it normally does. This keeps someone who is new from running a script and having it pop up, then disappear as soon as it's complete. I'm still looking around for an official word on this however.

Comment: @Kevin I've updated my question... this seems to come from calling a Batch file for the Wildfly CLI.

Comment: Can you give the contents of the jboss-cli.bat file?
Do you get the same Press any key message when you run the file via double-click?